# RabbitMQ: Unable to start rabbitmq_management plugin

Tags: rabbitmq

Version:

```
> sudo rabbitmqctl status | grep '{rabbit,"RabbitMQ",'
      {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.5.6"},
```

Error:

```
> sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

Plugin configuration unchanged.

Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@ip-172-31-26-169... failed.
 * Could not contact node rabbit@ip-172-31-26-169.
   Changes will take effect at broker restart.
 * Options: --online  - fail if broker cannot be contacted.
            --offline - do not try to contact broker.
```

Rabbit is running:

```
> sudo service rabbitmq-server status
Status of node 'rabbit@ip-172-31-26-169' ...
[{pid,22865},
..
```

Comment: Are these running  on separate machines? Is there definitely network connectivity between the two?

Comment: It's all on the same machine. I am still getting the same error, but I can access server:15672 now .. no idea why.

Comment: This it is often related to `.erlang.cookie`. are you using different  `.erlang.cookie` ?

Comment: Can you check any available log files, there may be some more detailed output hidden there.

Answer (score 3):

You need not necessary to contact broker if you are on the same machine.
so try this command

`>rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management --offline`

offline indicates that do not try to contact the broker.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error when trying to enable management console. To my suprise I typed http://localhost:15672/#/ in the browser and I could get to setup stuff through the management console. I had checked the availability of all the ports and everything looked good.
So I think that error is kind of misleading. Just try to go to the console in browser.

refs: http://arcware.net/installing-rabbitmq-on-windows/
[Failed to start rabbitmq-management plugin on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661791/failed-to-start-rabbitmq-management-plugin-on-windows)