# Cannot enable rabbitmq-management plugin on Windows

Tags: rabbitmq

So, this is what I've done:

1. Installed Erlang on my Windows x64 bit machine
2. Installed RabbitMQ
3. Started RabbitMQ service

At this step I have no errors. When, however, I try to enabe rabbitmq-management, I get some error messages in the console. The way I try to enable it is this one:

```
C:\...\rabbitmq-server-3.5.6\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management
```

This results in:

> Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@Jacobian... failed

To add to this, I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661791/failed-to-start-rabbitmq-management-plugin-on-windows) thread, but I'm not sure what this command means `SET HOMEDRIVE=C:`. Nevertheless, I tried it like so:

```
C:\...\rabbitmq-server-3.5.6\sbin>  SET HOMEDRIVE=C:
C:\...\rabbitmq-server-3.5.6\sbin>  rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management
```

But I still got the same error message. Thanks!

EDIT:

[image]

**EDIT**

It seems, like `RabbitMQ` became `RubbishMQ`. The catch is I followed very standard and very basic steps to install `RabbitMQ` now on Ubuntu machine and got a terrible list of error messages once again. These are the steps I followed:

```
apt-get install pkg-config automake autoconf libsigc++-2.0-dev 
git clone git://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c.git
cd rabbitmq-c
# Enable and update the codegen git submodule
git submodule init
git submodule update
# Configure, compile and install
autoreconf -i && ./configure && make && sudo make install 
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

When I run the last command I get tons of error messages. Among them I see such as "error_logger ... Error when reading ./.erlang.cookie: eaccess". So, I guess there are some secret missing steps or some voodoo spell, that can make it work. But I do not know all that stuff and hope to hear some advice. This is what I expect to see - 1) step by step installation of RabbitMQ on Windows and step by step test, that all works 2) the same for Ubuntu. Ready, Steady, Go!

Comment: What's the full stack error?

Comment: @Gabriele. Please, have a look.

Comment: It is a `.erlang.cookie` problem, please read this: https://www.rabbitmq.com/windows-quirks.html Copy the file .erlang.cookie manually from %SystemRoot% to %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%.

Comment: And in terms of Windows, what these paths mean? What systemroot? What homepath? You can make a full answer from this and I will definitely accept it!

Comment: It seems like nobody knows how to install and use RabbitMQ on Windows or Linux. Fantastic!

Comment: See this, May Helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661791/failed-to-start-rabbitmq-management-plugin-on-windows

Comment: @Dhaval Asodariya. I've already mentioned that thread in my own question ("To add to this, I know about this thread...." <-- have a look above), and I must confess that it is not useful any more.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I faced the same problem and my investigations led me to https://stackoverflow.com/a/34538688 which helped me solve it. After following the steps in that answer, start the service and the problem should be solved.

Basically, the problem is caused by the RabbitMQ installer not registering the service correctly.

Comment: I followed the same steps, still i am getting same error.

Comment: This should've been a comments instead of an answer ;P

Answer (score 20):

Somehow, this solved my issue from Command Prompt run as administrator.

`C:\...\rabbitmq-server-3.5.6\sbin>  SET HOMEDRIVE=C:
C:\...\rabbitmq-server-3.5.6\sbin>  rabbitmq-service remove
C:\...\rabbitmq-server-3.5.6\sbin>  rabbitmq-service install
C:\...\rabbitmq-server-3.5.6\sbin>  rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management`

Thanks @jacboian

Comment: Note: You need to stop and start rabbitmq-service after these instructions

Answer (score 11):

Check if this file `C:\Windows\.erlang.cookie` and this file `C:\Users\youruser\.erlang.cookie` are equals.

If not, copy `C:\Windows\.erlang.cookie` to `C:\Users\youruser\.erlang.cookie`

`youruser` is the windows user you are using to enable the management console. for example in my case: `C:\Users\gabriele\.erlang.cookie`

Comment: Unfortunatelly, sir, I must confess, that it does not help. I copied `C:\Windows\.erlang.cookie` to my home directory and restarted RabbitMQ, but to no avail. I still get thoese error messages when I try to enable plugins :(

Comment: That's strange, try to do the same executing the `rabbitmq-server.bat` and not service

Comment: At what stage should I do that? Before trying to enable plugins?

Comment: I tried to execute `rabbitmq-server.bat` and got `BOOT FAILED`. So, my all dozens attempts ended in failure.

Comment: you don't have to execute it using doubleclick, go to the `cmd` and execute it.

Comment: Actually, I ran it through `cmd` and not by doubleclicking.

Comment: This worked - Please make sure you remove the "Read Only" from users cookie  - Right click on file - Security - Uncheck "Read Only", Then copy it from C:\windows to home directory

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same problem, but none of presented solution helped me. Maybe someone will find my solution helpfull.

After running

```
rabbitmq-service.bat install
```

command I found that RabbitMQ service in windows service manager was added but didn't run. I turned it on manually and then

```
rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management
```

command runs perfectly.

After that http://localhost:15672 run successfully

Comment: worked as a charm

Answer (score 7):

As soon as I installed RabbitMQ I was not able to open localhost:15672 that was because i didnot enabled the plugins in order to enable that open "**RabbitMQ Command Prompt (sbin dir)**" and run the following command

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

It will enable all the plugins that is associated with the RabbitMQ.
Now open the browser and type http://localhost:15672 it will open a RabbitMQ console login with "guest as username" and "guest as password".

Answer (score 6):

Try: rabbitmq-server start.
Worked for me

Comment: Does not work. I'm getting "init terminating in do_boot" error message

Answer (score 4):

open powershell at

`C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.14\sbin>`

and run

`.\rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management`

then if you encounter this error:

```
 ******************************
 ERLANG_HOME not set correctly.
 ******************************

 Please either set ERLANG_HOME to point to your Erlang installation or place 
 the RabbitMQ server distribution in the Erlang lib folder.
```

go to [ERLANG_HOME-StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323621/windows-x64-rabbitmq-install-error-with-erlang-environment-var-erlang-home/56091892#56091892)

Answer (score 3):

Suprisingly, running

```
rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management
```

instead of

```
rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq-management
```

worked for me. I don't know the reason, but it's a quick fix to try (using underscore instead of dash).

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps I did to fix the problem.

1. Remove RabbitMQ and Erlang
2. Remove registry entries under HKLM/SOFTWARE/Ericsson/Erlang/ErlSrv.
3. Remove all .erlang.cookie (possibly in %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% and %SYSTEMROOT%)
4. Install Erlang then RabbitMQ WITH ADMIN USER.
5. Make sure in system environment, ERLANG_HOME with C:\Program Files\erl*your version number* exist. If not, create.
6. Run rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management from RabbitMQ sbin folder

Answer (score 1):

Check compatibility of ERLANG AND RabbitMQ server version 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html
Download and install compatible version for both. After that there's no need to set ERLANG path in system variable.

It worked for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling the `RabbitMQ`, I also faced this issue.

Fixed the issue by doing,

Uninstall both Erlang and RabbitMQ. and restart the computer. then again install the RabbitMQ and relevant Erlang.

Then followed the following steps.

1. Open CMD in administarion mode.
2. Change the directory in Windows Command to the RabbitMQ `sbin` folder:

[image]

3. Enter the following commands:

   `rabbitmq-service.bat stop`

press Enter

`rabbitmq-service.bat remove`

Press Enter

```
rabbitmq-service.bat install
```

Press Enter

```
rabbitmq-service.bat start
```

Press Enter

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to make it work even after trying other solutions, just use Docker. It is the best and quickest way to run RabbitMQ.

Please note, you need to have docker installed on your machine and then run the below commands.

Step 1: Pull the rabbitmq docker image

> docker pull rabbitmq:3-management

Step 2: Run it

> docker run --rm -it -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management

You can access RabbitMQ at http://localhost:15672

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinstall RabbitMq, that's just that the file *enabled_plugins* is not located in the right place.

On Windows Server 2019, the (required) file, *enabled_plugins* was not located in the right place.

I had do copy it from C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\enabled_plugins to the folder of another user, for example C:\Users\Uer2\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ
This answer helped me to find the answer : https://serverfault.com/a/500046

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while running the cmd

```bash
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

After I checked the supported versions of rabbitMQ and ERLang in this page "https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html", I reinstalled the Rabbit MQ. Issue resolved.

Answer (score -1):

set Port Protocols and Ports  Type "IPv6" Local port ALL
Windows firewall with advanced security

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33487893)