# Run "rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management" .. failed

Tags: plugins, rabbitmq

Firstly, installed

1. erlang
2. rabbitmqserver

Then, try to run command to enable plugin like the following:

---

C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.9\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

Plugin configuration unchanged.

Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@PVGN50886410A... failed.

- Could not contact node rabbit@PVGN50886410A.
  Changes will take effect at broker restart.
- Options: --online  - fail if broker cannot be contacted.
          --offline - do not try to contact broker.

C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.9\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_priority_queue

Error: The following plugins could not be found:
  rabbitmq_priority_queue

---

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

check this link: 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/windows-quirks.html

> This makes it impossible to use rabbitmqctl.
>
> Workarounds:
>
> Run the installer as an administrator or Copy the file `.erlang.cookie`
>   manually from `%SystemRoot%` to  `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%.`

and also check this answer:

[Cannot enable rabbitmq-management plugin on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951516/cannot-enable-rabbitmq-management-plugin-on-windows/33953581#33953581)

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue in my windows 10 machine and figured the root cause of this issue. Prior to install the Rabbit MQ server in my machine, I am using Active MQ server and this service running by default.

So, what I did was just stopped the Active MQ service and removed service for rabbit mq too. Freshly, I started rabbit mq server then installed plugin and it's working for me. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, [this](http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/not-able-to-enable-any-plugin-td28027.html) thread helped me: I reinstalled erlang, rabbitmq and deleted Windows registries HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ericsson\Erlang and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Ericsson\Erlang

After reinstallation, didn't have to issue the plugin enabling command.

I use erlang 9.2 and rabbitmq 3.7.3.